# how do i "check" my songs in Itunes

Tags: itunes, windows

I'm on PC with Microsoft Windows Vista.  iTunes was stuck for forced it to close.  When I reopened iTunes all 5000 of my songs were unchecked.

How do I put the check mark back on all of them?

Comment: Thank You!!Worked wierd.  I selected about 20 songs to test, checked the box at the top,  and it check the whole 5000.  Is 5k song a lot to manage with I tunes?

Answer (score 1):

Select all the Songs:

Then  <kbd>crtl</kbd> click to get the contextual menu.
Select ***Check Selection***

[image]

This is assuming that the PC version of iTunes has the same menu system.